# Entity Framework add property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my .net mvc project I have a class named company;

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string firmName { get; set; }
    public string firmContact { get; set; }
```

The first run is successful and database integration is done. but later on i am adding a new property named **"firmAddr"**. There is a column in the database, but the data in it is null. It does not send any value during update and insert.
***I'm using "DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges"**
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using some kind of mapper? Without seeing any overrides on dbContext or controllers it's hard to guess.

Comment: I did not use an additional override. I just use the structure to ef.